# okhttp3.OkHttpClient - A connection to any_host was leaked.Did you forget to close a response body?

Tags: okhttp

In my Kotlin's project I use `okhttp3`

Here example to connect to remote host:

```
    import okhttp3.*
    import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor

var оkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()        оkHttpClient.newCall(requestNegotiate).enqueue(object : Callback {
             override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                  ...
             }}
```

and is's work fine.

But after few minutes I get many times the next message:

```
  2019-02-13 18:39:39,197 675399 [OkHttp ConnectionPool] WARN  okhttp3.OkHttpClient - A connection to any_host_com was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body? To see where this was allocated, set the OkHttpClient logger level to FINE: Logger.getLogger(OkHttpClient.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.FINE);
```